# Why is there a gameObject inside a GameObject

Tags: unity, gameobject

In order to manipulate a game object via script in Unity I need to access the `gameObject` inside the *main* `GameObject`.

Why is it structured this way?  What is the *main* `GameObject` representing compared to the `gameObject`?

```
public class Sun : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] _satelliteGameObjects;
    private Rigidbody[] _satelliteRigidBodies;
    public GameObject[] Satellites;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (Satellites == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"You haven't added a {nameof(Satellites)}.'");
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(Satellites)} should not be null");
        }

        _satelliteRigidBodies = new Rigidbody[Satellites.Length];
        _satelliteGameObjects = new GameObject[Satellites.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < Satellites.Length; i++)
        {
            var satellite = Satellites[i];
            _satelliteRigidBodies[i] = Satellites[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            _satelliteGameObjects[i] = Satellites[i].gameObject;
            _satelliteRigidBodies[i].AddForce(Vector3.up * 100);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, I'm passing a `GameObject` into this class.  However, in order to call members on the *actual* game object, I need to go through the `gameObject` property.

Comment: The keyword `this` will access a script instance, which is a component of a `GameObject`. The script is not `GameObject`. And I'm confused, what do you mean by *main GameObject*?

Comment: Can you give us an example of code that does what you describe? If you mean what @trollingchar mentions (as in using `this.gameObject`) then that's not a `GameObject` inside a `GameObject`.

Comment: @trollingchar Added,

Comment: @TomTsagk Added,

Comment: You actually *can* write `satelliteRigidBodies[i] = satellite.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` and `_satelliteGameObjects[i] = satellite;` And if you are not going to use rigidbodies in `Update`, you don't need the array at all.

Comment: Thanks @trollingchar.  Those things are used, there didn't seem to be much to gain from posting the entire class.

Comment: @trollingchar You're right.  `ReferenceEquals(_satelliteGameObjects[0], _satelliteGameObjects[0].gameObject)` returns `true`.  Why's it there then if it's just a reference back to itself?

Comment: @BanksySan Some of unity classes, like `Transform`, have redundant refs to self but I don't know why.

Comment: This is interesting to me, in so far as the documentation makes no reference to GameObject.gameObject existing anymore (even as far back as version 5.2). Is this still current Unity behaviour, and if so - am I just looking at the wrong part of the docs (note, no difference across all versions 5.2->2020.1): https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.html

Comment: By the way, when you are looping over all entries in an array or List, you can use the [C# foreach syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

Answer (score 1):

GameObject is a unity class. These are things in your scene. Most unity scripts you write are *components* that are attached to these game objects. These are scripts that are subclasses of the MonoBehaviour class not GameObject.

BUT... Since MonoBehaviours are always attached to a GameObject, the MonoBehaviour class gives you an easy way to get a reference to that GameObject through the gameObject field. This is the main way you access other components on the object including the Transform and Rigidbody component etc.

In summary:

capital GameObject is a class.

Lowercase gameObject is a field in MonoBehaviour scripts that lets you access the GameObject the MonoBehakviour is attached to.

Comment: `_satalite[i]` is an instance of `GameObject` though, yet it has a property `gameObject` which references itself.  That's weird.  I'd never write a class `Foo` that had a property `foo` that just pointed back to the instance (i.e. `this`).

Comment: As far as I can tell The gameObject field on a game object is redundant. You dont need it at all since you can just call myobject.SetActive(true) etc. I suspect it’s there to make it easier to refactor code from referencing other components to referencing game objects.

Answer (score 0):

you have nested gameObjects or Prefabs for more flexiblity and function. if an object is Parented by another, it derives many behaviors from parent object like movement and rotation etc...

if you want to access a child of object or parent of object you should use transform like this:

```
 void Awake() 
    {
        GameObject parent = transform.parent.gameObject;
        GameObject firstChild = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that is close to what I'm asking.  The parent & children in this example all need to use the `gameObject` property.  What to `parent` and the elements returned by `GetChild(0)` point to?

Comment: can you explain more what you want? do you look for components?

Comment: Nothing's broken, my game seems to work just fine.   I'm just trying to get things in context in my head, I've only been doing this for a week so my understanding of how bits fit together is pretty cluttered.