# What is the purpose of `gameObject` property inside `GameObject` class?

Tags: unity, gameobject

There is this property defined in the `GameObject` class:

```
public sealed class GameObject : Object
{
    ...
    public GameObject gameObject => this;
    ...
}
```

What is the purpose of such property?

---

After a quick research I've found [duplicate](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/175974/159972), which would be hard to fix and make it canonical for Unity beginners like myself. It has some valuable comments, but no correct and accepted answer yet.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  Good question.  I suspect they did it to be uniform with https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html

Comment: Early Unity versions had an enormous emphasis on beginner friendly. Back in the day there were relatively small number of built in components and they were cached (i.e. not needing GetComponent but same like how transform is now). Despite in the end being more confuning  as @Evorlor said it maybe was added in hope to make it all more uniform and simpler for beginners.

Comment: As much as I like this question, I am closing it as opinion-based, because we can't really answer it unless the original author comes by.